Animation: Is there a way to change degrees of rotation along local axys when keyframes have already set up?
For example, I choose some bone in Pose Mode, insert keyframe, then jump to frame 30, rotate bone for 8 degrees along predefined custom local Z axys and insert keyframe. So, I have 30-frames animation of bone rotating along local Z axys.
I know that I can easily edit and shift keyframes in Dope Sheet editor making animation longer or shorter. But my qiestion is: Can I change degrees of rotation? For example change bone rotation to ten or twelwe degrees without changing keyframes?
Thank you.
